# How to connect three tables using only one entity/class in Spring & Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I have only one entity which is School - a class (example). I have 7 fields in there and those fields are from 3 different tables. The first table for example is called Classroom, second is the Teachers, third is Subject. The teachers and subject table are connected by a pk: subject_id while the classroom table and teachers table are connected by classroom_id.

I tried secondary tables but it looks like it's not correct. How to connect those tables inside a single entity and write a query in the DAO IMPLementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Entity per Table.
If you need to select into non database related Model class, you can be done easily with spring-data-jpa.

After create the Model class (like School) just use the following sample to query:

```
class ProgrammerNameAndCity{
   fields...
   allArgConstructor...
}

public interface ProgrammerRepository extends JpaRepository<Programmer,Long> {
    @Query(" select new com.zlrx.database.pojo.ProgrammerNameAndCity(p.name,p.address.city) " +
                "from Programmer p where  p.idNumber=?1")
    ProgrammerNameAndCity findNameAndCityByIdNumber(String idNumber);
}
```

In this example the programmer has an address field (OneToOne), but you can create any kind of query, the important thing here is the constructor call of the model.

If you want to use plain sql or impl class instead of interface to query, you can use Spring's RowMapper too.

Comment: i can use this if we are told to do our own implementation. this is cool and helpful. although, i dont know why they gave us only one class for three tables...

Answer (score -1):

```
class ProgrammerNameAndCity{
    fields...
    allArgConstructor...
}

public interface ProgrammerRepository extends JpaRepository<Programmer,Long> {
    @Query(" select new com.zlrx.database.pojo.ProgrammerNameAndCity(p.name,p.address.city) "
        + "from Programmer p where  p.idNumber=?1")
    ProgrammerNameAndCity findNameAndCityByIdNumber(String idNumber);
}
```

Comment: ?? copy of my answer :)